# Remove item from SPFieldLookupValueCollection

Tags: development, sharepoint-foundation

I have a multilookup column "Employee". i wanted to remove one value from the column. Below is the code

```
        using (SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb())
        {
            SPList TestB = web.Lists["TestB"];
            SPListItemCollection Items = TestB.Items;
            foreach (SPListItem Item in Items)
            {
                SPFieldLookupValueCollection objLookupFieldValueCol = (SPFieldLookupValueCollection)Item["Employee"];
                SPFieldLookupValue lookupValue = new SPFieldLookupValue();
                lookupValue.LookupId = 19;
                objLookupFieldValueCol.Remove(lookupValue);
                Item["Employee"] = objLookupFieldValueCol.ToString();
                Item.Update();

            }
        }
```

The above code executing without any error but not removing any item. Any suggesstions?

Answer (score 2):

```
objLookupFieldValueCol.Remove(objLookupFieldValueCol.Find(delegate(SPFieldLookupValue LV){return LV.LookupId == ItemID;}));
```

I tried it's working.. to remove lookup id in SPFieldLookupValueCollection.